# Current through the secondary of a transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

If I know the wattage of the primary of a transformer, and the input voltage, how do I calculate the current flowing through the secondary, if a load of some resistance is placed across the secondary?

Comment: For one thing, you need to know the transformer turns ratio

Comment: @BobD, The question is a bit ambiguous (e.g., what does "wattage of the primary" mean?), but assuming that it question asks about an ideal, lossless transformer, then the power that is delivered by an external circuit to the primary must be the same as the power that is delivered to the resistive load by the secondary. If you know the power that is dissipated by a resistor, then you can compute the current that is flowing through it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I agree it's ambiguous. Without being told the transformer is ideal, the primary wattage is not enough information. Why don't you submit your comment as an answer?